# WPF Custom buttons

Tags: c#, wpf, templates, button, custom-controls

I would like to make 4 custom buttons, however the shape I want is quite unusual and I'm stuck on how to make it. 
Each different section is exactly the shape I want the button, is it possible?
[Button shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/am2I1.png)

Thanks

Comment: you could make 4 buttons, and place a section of the image as the content, with that section. Then you could remove the background, the borders of the button.

Comment: How do I remove the borders of the basic button?

Comment: Go into the template of the button and set what you want in there. In the `ControlTemplate` set `Background` to `Transparent`, `BorderThickness` to `0`, and do whatever with the `VisualState`s based on the kind of MouseOver, Pressed, whatever look you're going for with the images.

Comment: Done this, backbround is transparent and border thickness 0 etc.  Will the MouseOver activate though if the actual border of the button(rather than the image inside)  is bigger than the image?

Comment: How do I get the mouseover to ignore the background?

Comment: @elszeus in the `VisualStateManager` in the template. Just make the `<VisualState x:Name="MouseOver" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per our discussion in the comments, here's a sample template for one of your buttons:

```
<Style x:Key="QuarterButtonTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
    <EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="QuarterButton_Click" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border CornerRadius="0"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        Padding="4,0">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver" />
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Focused" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused" />
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                      VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}"
                                      Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                      Margin="{TemplateBinding Margin}" />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

That gives you a `Button` that basically does nothing but look like an image with nothing to denote anything other than a `Click` event. If you mouse over, disable, focus, de-focus, or click on it, it will look the same because of the empty `VisualState`s.